# Error decoding data from Sensocar SCA4 weighing machine using RS232 to USB connection in CRM development

Tags: flutter, decoding

I am developing a CRM for a company and I'm currently working on integrating a Sensocar SCA4 weighing machine into the system. The weighing machine is connected to the computer via RS232, which is plugged into a USB port (COM3). I have successfully read the data from the machine, but I'm facing an issue with decoding the data.

Here is the error message I'm receiving:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Missing extension byte (at offset 2)
#0 _Utf8Decoder.convertSingle (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1747)
#1 Utf8Decoder.convert (dart:convert/utf.dart:351)
#2 Utf8Codec.decode (dart:convert/utf.dart:63)
#3 WeighingMachine.GetWeight.<anonymous closure> (package:truckcrm/Utilities/WeighingMachine.dart:70)
#4 _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1593)
#5 _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339)
#6 _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:515)
#7 _PendingEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:620)
#8 _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591)
#9 _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40)
#10 _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49)
```

I believe the error is related to the decoding process. Could anyone provide insights into what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

How can I have the weighing machine display the weight in my CRM, which is made using flutter?